# Upgrade from magento 2.3.1 to magento 2.3.2 catalog search advance error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2

Recently i have upgraded magento 2.3.1 to magento 2.3.2 after upgrading i am getting below mentioned error in system.log file.

```
Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced, Return value of Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\ItemCollectionProvider::getCollection() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Data\Collection, instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory returned [] []
```

And when trying to open advance search getting below mentioned error trace.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:160]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:246]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]
#5 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]
#6 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#7 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/BlockFactory.php:46]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory->createBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:268]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:248]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:226]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:134]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:81]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:343]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:89]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [app/code/Swissup/Ajaxpro/Model/View/Layout/Builder.php:102]
#16 Swissup\Ajaxpro\Model\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:212]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:225]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->publicBuild() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Page/Config/Interceptor.php:37]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Interceptor->publicBuild() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:242]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:130]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:141]
#27 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:40]
</pre>
```

It would be great if someone able to help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is magentoo bug. Please open file

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Search/ItemCollectionProvider.php
```

and change line 46

```
return $this->factories['default'];
```

to

```
return $this->factories['default']->create();
```